# Dificuldades com a seleção de itens em uma QTreeView

Tags: c++, mvc, qt

### Cenário:

Eu tenho uma aplicação que gerencia uma lista de imagens de faces humanas com expressões emocionais prototípicas.

Criei uma classe herdada de `QAbstractListModel` para fornecer o modelo (*model*) de acesso aos dados e estou usando duas classes de visualização (*view*) nativas do Qt para exibir a lista ao usuário: uma `QListView` para exibição de "ícones" (miniaturas das imagens na lista) e uma `QTreeView` para exibição de detalhes (formato tabular, com o nome da imagem e o rótulo emocional).

Ambas as classes de visualização usam o mesmo controle de seleção (uma instância padrão de `QItemSelectionModel` criada com referência ao modelo mencionado acima). Assim, quando o usuário clica/seleciona um ou mais imagens em uma visão a seleção é reproduzida na outra.

A instância de `QTreeView` (todos os componentes foram adicionados no Qt Designer e são carregados no arquivo .ui) está configurada (na propriedade `selectionBehavior`) para seleção por linhas, conforme imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Problema:

O problema é que, apesar do componente `QTreeView` estar exibindo corretamente a seleção em toda a linha quando o usuário interage com ele, o componente ainda seleciona os itens individualmente (e por item entenda qualquer célula em uma linha e coluna). Assim, por exemplo, caso o usuário selecione dois itens na visão do `QListView`, altere para a visão do `QTreeView` e selecione mais um item (mantendo a tecla <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressionada) clicando na segunda coluna, o resultado visual é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note como na visão do `QTreeView` (a direita) a célula da 4a linha 2a coluna tem uma borda sutil indicando o último item selecionado, e as demais linhas (que foram originalmente selecionadas na visão da esquerda) não apresentam a linha totalmente selecionada.

Além do problema visual, há também um mais grave no momento do processamento dos itens selecionados. O código abaixo, por exemplo, é usado para remover as imagens selecionadas do arquivo atual. Idealmente são três (3) as imagens selecionadas (Angelina, Brad e Scarlett), porém a chamada de `selectedIndexes()` no objeto de gerenciamento da seleção retorna quatro (4) itens (já que ele considera individualmente as células).

```
ChildWindow *pChild = (ChildWindow*) ui->tabWidget->currentWidget();
if(!pChild)
    return;

QModelIndexList lsSelected = pChild->getSelectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
if(lsSelected.size() > 0)
{
    QString sMsg;
    if(lsSelected.size() == 1)
        sMsg = tr("Você confirma a remoção da imagem selecionada?");
    else
        sMsg = tr("Você confirma a remoção das %1 imagens selecionadas?").arg(lsSelected.size());
    if(QMessageBox::question(this, tr("Confirmação da remoção"), sMsg, QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        vector<int> vIndexes;
        for(int i = 0; i < lsSelected.size(); i++)
            vIndexes.push_back(lsSelected[i].row());
        pChild->removeImages(vIndexes);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu cheguei a testar utilizando a chamada de `selectedRows()` ao invés de `selectedItems()`, mas o problema continua (embora levemente distinto). O número de linhas só considera aquelas totalmente selecionadas por meio da visão do `QTreeView` e sempre ignora os itens selecionados "parcialmente" por meio do `QListView`.

Enfim, a pergunta é: como eu faço para forçar o `QTreeView` a sempre exibir as linhas completamente selecionadas e garantir que apenas os itens da primeira coluna sejam realmente selecionados?

Comment: Tentou dar um reset no model quando é feita a transição? (tou só chutando, não testei). Não prometo, mas se sobrar um tempinho mais tarde tento reproduzir o problema aqui pra tentar esquentar os miolos em busca de solução também :)

Comment: @Bacco Você diz a transição de *views* né? Acabei de fazer o teste, mas como eu imaginava o *reset* no *model* faz ele perder toda a seleção (afinal, foi tudo reiniciado né?). Valeu pela ajuda. :)

Comment: Qual é configuração do seu ListView? O `selectionBehavior` está como `SelectRows`?

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Rapaz, acertou na mosca! Era isso mesmo. :) Caramba, como o `ListView` sempre exibe itens eu nem considerei que ele *também* teria essa configuração (não me liguei que essa é uma propriedade herdada de `QAbstractItemView` e por isso vale pros dois, mesmo a lista não exibindo as demais colunas). Envia como resposta que eu aceito e já te dou a recompensa. Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É preciso configurar a propriedade `selectionBehavior` do ListView para o valor `SelectRows`.
Se não, o ListView estraga a sua seleção.

Para quem quiser testar, use o exemplo `interview` incluído no QtCreator.
Adicione a seguinte linha no arquivo `main.cpp`:

```
list->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

Comment: Marcos, o sistema ainda não permite que eu conceda a recompensa (só daqui a 17 horas). Depois eu te dou ela, ok? :)

Comment: Entendido. Só gostaria de pedir, para que nas futuras perguntas, fosse dito qual a versão do Qt usada. No começo, pensei que poderia ser um bug na versão do Windows. Ficaria complicado testar o problema no Windows, Linux com Qt4, Qt5.

Comment: Verdade. Se tivesse me lembrado antes eu teria editado a pergunta e colocado, mas acho que agora é desnecessário.